# How to make a multi-page web app with Vuetify.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, config, multi-page-application

It is easy to build a multi-page app of Vue can be building by editing the `vue.config.js` file. But yesterday afternoon, when I was trying to build a multi-page web app with some ui structures in `Vuetify.js` instead of pure `vue.js`, one weird thing happened:

It is a two page application: the home page and signup page. When I run `npm run build`, the result `dist` folder does not contain the `.html` file of the second page.

SO I run some tests: here are what is happening:

1. If the home page has a filename of `index.html` in `vue.config.js` and the second page has a filename of `second.html`, then everything is fine.
2. If the home page has a filename of `index.html` in `vue.config.js` while the second page has a filename of `/second/second.html` or `second/index.html`. Then, the folder named `second` will not be created, neither does the file `/second/second.html` which is in it.

Does anyone have issues similar to this before, really appreciate for the helps.

---

Also, I notice that when it was just pure `vue.js`, the assets such as images will be put into a separate folder in `dist`. But after `vuetify.js` is added to the project, the only folders can appear in `dist` is the `js` and `css` and `fonts`, those image assets will be store under the folder `dist`. I am not sure if it is a feature of the newest `vue.js` version, or it is also caused by configuration of `vuetify.js`. Thanks for the help.

---

I find that all the stylesheets and javascript code for the second page is generated in folder `css` and `js`, the only one missing is the html template.

---

During building the app, there are no errors about cannot create the folder. All it have be printing is the warning for the asset size since I didn't import assets by part, the prints are:

```
entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  home (1.54 MiB)
      css/chunk-vendors.c6dfe063.css
      js/chunk-vendors.216b9b9d.js
      css/home.429de16e.css
      js/home.635f35e5.js
  signup (1.53 MiB)
      css/chunk-vendors.c6dfe063.css
      js/chunk-vendors.216b9b9d.js
      css/signup.d6876e84.css
      js/signup.77b83ca7.js
```

The home is the index file, and the second page is referening to the signup page.

---

```
module.exports = {
  pages: {
    home: {
      entry: 'src/main.js',
      template: 'public/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      title: 'home'
    },
    signup: {
      entry: 'src/pages/signup/main.js',
      template: 'public/signup.html',
      filename: '/signup/index.html',
      title: 'signup page'
    }
  },
  transpileDependencies: [
    'vuetify'
  ]
}
```

As you can see, I put all the html templates in the `public` folder. And I wish all the built html files will be named as index.html under some certain folder so I won't see html from the url of my small project.

Comment: _"everything is fine. Then the folder second will not be created"_  this doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: Sorry about that, I was going to say a folder named as `second`. I will fix that.

Comment: It would go a long way to solving your problem if you shared your actual `vue.config.js` file

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Does the built app works ? It makes me thing at the VRouter witch is included in Vuetify.js.

Comment: Could you be a little bit more specific, really appreciate the help.